# Show a thumbnail caption on hover centered

Tags: html, css, hover, caption

I'm trying to show a thumbnail caption on hover centered: aligned horizontal and vertical, but not successful.

In the fiddle you see a responsive thumbnail grid with on hover a caption. I gave it a dashed red border so you can see that it is not same size as the thumbnail. I can't get the title caption to be centered in the thumbnail. Maybe my thumbnail grid need a different build. Hope someone can help me.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/a0zwecou/9/)

```
#content {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 110px 40px 100px 40px;
background-color: transparent;
}

.col-25 {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 25%;
margin: 0;
}

.thumb {
display: block;
margin: 10px;
}

.col-25 img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.col-25 a:hover img {
opacity: 0.1;
}

.caption {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
border: dashed 1px red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity: 0;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
z-index:2;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.col-25 a:hover .caption {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.thumb:hover{border:1px dashed red;background-color:red;}

.caption {
position: absolute;
top:40%;
left:0;
/*border: dashed 1px red;*/ //remove it
width:100%;
/*height:100%;*/ // remove it
opacity: 0;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
z-index:2;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/a0zwecou/20/

Comment: Thank you but it is not really centered

Comment: With 40% it is centered, but is it possible to when using a background color for the caption to cover exactly the thumbnail size?

Comment: Check my updated answer for thumb hover background color. 
Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/a0zwecou/20/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/a0zwecou/14/

I have added an inner div to caption and give it a margin height of 25%. Remove the margin for extremely small width size in your media query.

```
    <div class="caption">
          <div class="inner-caption">
              <h3>Untitled for now</h3>
              <p>Caption</p>
          </div>
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
.inner-caption{margin-top:25%;}
```

Comment: Thanks yours works the best! Is it possible to remove the outer margin of the caption so when using a background color it is the same size as the thumbnail?

Comment: The best I can think of is having the image as background of thumbnail with height,width of 100%. And then removing the background on hover.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/a0zwecou/22/](http://jsfiddle.net/a0zwecou/22/) I assume this is how you want it.

Comment: Thanks but there is still some space under the thumbnail and now it pushes thumbnails underneath it away.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a0zwecou/15/)

only by changing the height and adding padding to caption class.

```
.caption {
position: absolute;
padding-top:25%;
top:0;
left:0;
border: dashed 1px red;
width:100%;
height:60%;
opacity: 0;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
z-index:2;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hosein! looks like it works and simple. But you say changing the width but you mean properly the height?

Comment: Is it possible to when using a background color for the caption to cover exactly the thumbnail size? Now it overlaps the thumbnail.

Comment: remove margin : 10px; from thumb class.

Comment: Can't that will cause collapsing of the thumbnails grid so there isn't a 20 px (10+10px) gap.

Answer (score 0):

see the fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a0zwecou/13/
and add css:

```
.caption h3 {
    margin-top: 59px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your caption inside another div and centered that with transate(with all prefixes of course), OR you can simply center that using tables (table + table-cell)
[HERE THE PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwMaMz), hover the first.

```
.insideCap{
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

OTHER WAY:

```
parent{
  dispaly:table;
}
son{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this:
<div id="content">


HTML:
Add this div:

    <div class="col-25">
            <a class="thumb" href="#">
                <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x310/999/">
                    <div class="caption"><div class="caption-text"><h3>Untitled for now</h3><p>Caption</p></div></div>
            </a>
        </div>

CSS:
add this css in your style:
.caption-text {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 32%;
}
```

SEE [JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/9rth8kg4/)

Comment: Thank you, but isn't working what i want to achieve.